# Does Firebase Realtime Database guarantees FCFS order when serving requests?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is rather just a straight forward question.

Does Firebase Realtime Database guarantees to follow 'First come first serve' rule when handling requests?

But when there is a write-request, and then instantaneously followed by a read-request, is the read-request will fetch updated data?

When there is a write-read-write sequence of requests, does for sure read-request fetch the data written by first write?

Suppose there is a write-request, which was unable to perform (due to some connection issues). As firebase can work even in offline, that change will be saved locally. Now from somewhere else another write-request was made and it completed successfully. After this, if the first device comes online, does it modify the values(since it arrived latest)? or not(since it was initiated prior to the latest changes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questions in your post, and many of them depend on how you implement the functionality. So it's not nearly as straightforward as you may think.

The best I can do is explain a bit of how the database works in the scenarios you mention. If you run into more questions from there, I recommend implementing the use-case and posting back with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for each specific question.

- Writes from a single client are handled in the order in which that client makes them.
- But writes from different clients are handled with a last-write-wins logic. If your use-case requires something else, include a client-side timestamp in the write and use security rules to reject writes that are older than the current state.
- Firebase synchronizes state to the listeners, and not necessarily all (write) events that led to this state. So it is possible (and fairly common) for listeners to not get all state changes that happened, for example if multiple changes to the same state happened while they were offline.
- A read of data on a client that this client itself has changed, will always see the state including its own changes.

Comment: In second case, 'last-write' is decided based on when that write was actually initiated. Right?

Comment: Unless you do something for it, the last write to reach the server "wins". That's why I show a way to indeed get something closer to "last write that was started on a client".